# Country on Google Play from Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

**Background:** I'm trying to get the Nexus 10 16GB, which has intermittent availability in Spain.

**Problem:** When I'm accessing Google Play website from a Windows 8 PC, it shows me the prices in $ instead of in €, and it won't accept my address as a valid delivery address.

However, it does show everything correctly, and it does accept my address, when I access the same url from:

- a Nexus 7 or a Galaxy Nexus associated with the same Google account, from the same WiFi (same public IP)
- Chrome and MSIE from Windows 7 inside a VirtualBox VM on the same Windows 8 PC

So is there a way to force Google Play, or Chrome, or Windows 8, to realize I am indeed connecting from a PC located in Spain?

- My Google Account location is set to Spain.
- I have tried with: Chrome, Opera and Internet Explorer.
- Windows 8 is set to Location: Spain
- Chrome location sharing is enabled.
- Incognito windows in Chrome show the same behaviour.
- Changing Windows 8 interface language to English or Spanish has no effect.

Comment: Do you have any other Windows machine that experiences similar problems.  I assume the Nexus 10 when you access the store indicates the correct store price?

Comment: Does a Windows 8 Virtual Machine also experience this same problem?